# How can I use GreyAssert in element's existence/visibility check?

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, earlgrey

I just started using EarlGrey, and now I try to realize construction which will make screenshot if the test fails on Assert.
It is rather simple, e.g. when I check if the keyboard is visible, because `GREYKeyboard.waitForKeyboardToAppear()` returns Bool:

```
let image = GREYScreenshotUtil.takeScreenshot()
GREYScreenshotUtil.saveImage(asPNG: image, toFile: "\(testMethodName).png", inDirectory: path/to/necessary/directory)
GreyAssert(GREYKeyboard.waitForKeyboardToAppear(), "Keyboard is not active")  //works correct
```

But if I want to check the same way if some element (for example, button or text field) I can't just use `grey_sufficientlyVisible()`, and most of other matchers return non-Bool.

I know that `.assert(with: )` exists, but it's not so versatile.
So, is there any way to make this working?

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to assert again? If the keyboard is Visible?

Comment: @gran_profaci , That was the example which works, because `waitForKeyBoardToAppear` returns Bool. I'm trying to assert the visibility of different elements (like buttons and text fields).